# How to create a new user with custom required fields in Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am using Parse and created a new colums in the User. I set the field to "Required", but now I can't create a user anymore.

Error i get:

```
Login failed: ParseError code=142 error=myCustomColumn is required
```

This is how I did it:

```
do {
    let currentUser = try User.signup(username: "user", password: "password")
    print("Login succes: \(currentUser)")
} catch {
    print("Login failed: \(error)")
}
```

How can I set my custom field? It's already created in the struct. I just need to set the value.

I am using ParseSwift.

https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-Swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by using the instance version of signUp in the [documentation](http://parseplatform.org/Parse-Swift/api/Protocols/ParseUser.html#/s:10ParseSwift0A4UserPAAE6signup7options13callbackQueue10completionyShyAA3APIV6OptionOG_So17OS_dispatch_queueCys6ResultOyxAA0A5ErrorVGctF). An example is shown in the playgrounds:

```swift
//: To add additional information when signing up a user,
//: you should create an instance of your user first.
var newUser = User(username: "parse", password: "aPassword*", email: "parse@parse.com")
//: Add any other additional information.
newUser.targetScore = .init(score: 40)
newUser.signup { result in

    switch result {
    case .success(let user):

        guard let currentUser = User.current else {
            assertionFailure("Error: current user not stored locally")
            return
        }
        assert(currentUser.hasSameObjectId(as: user))
        print("Successfully signed up as user: \(user)")

    case .failure(let error):
        print("Error logging in: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Also, in my example above, I’m signing up asynchronously, which is most likely the way you want to signup. In your example, you are signing up synchronously, which can hold up the main queue and cause run-time warnings in Xcode